# Windows 10 - extreme input lags

Tags: windows-10, desktop-computer, lag

Since a longer time i get **extreme** keyboard input lag. Sometimes its just a second delay but it can be for up to a minute. While playing or writing its not fun at all. Below some short notes:

1. CPU  during lag is ok and is around 5 to 40%
2. HDD is far away from being busy during lags
3. Temperatur CPU 28°C and Motherboard 30°C last time it occured
4. Sometimes it is only for a minute, sometimes it lasts for way longer times
5. JAVA has been uninstalled
6. Someone told me to use Razer Boost Software (did not help!)
7. Keyboard Battery Status is at 100% (tested it with wired keyboard - same issue)
8. Using Windows 10 now but it was same issue with Windows 7 before!
9. When lagging it concerns all Software running i.e. games, editors etc...
10. Using Chrome. Lags persist if I end all Chrome tasks.
11. I am using Avira AntiVir (Free version). (Does this effect keyboard input?)
12. Lag only for Keyboard. Mouse and other Input such as Audio works like a charm.

I read through various threads in the internet with people having similar issues but found nothing that matched this exact problem. For most of them uninstalling Java helped....

Thanks so much for all the comments

Regards
André

Comment: Try to preform a clean boot as described over here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135. So disable every program on boot and all services.

Comment: I can only see if this error occurs while playing some games. Due to the reason that it sometimes Occurs after hours and sometimes not at all (its pretty difficult to write consequently without breaks for hours or even days ;-))....I actually need some of the services anyway so i can play .... Isnt there another way to find out?